# Stopping score count after player is destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make my first game but I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I can't seem to figure out how to check if the player is dead and stop score count. Also I want to know how to store that score.

My game is simple. You have to dodge a lot of spheres for as long as you can and get the high score.

But when my player collides with one of the spheres, the game still carries on. I have a "**Move Forward**" script for the enemy spheres that move at a certain speed, and a "**Destroy Out of Bounds**" script for when the spheres pass the player, they get destroyed off-screen and add 5 points to the score. I do have the "**Game Manager**" script that spawns all the spheres and to show the current score. (I may need to re-route some coding right?)

Here's what's in my Game Manager script. I need to know how to really check if the player is dead when something happens.

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] EnemyPrefabs;
    private float spawnRangeX = 17;
    private float spawnPosZ = 35;
    private float StartDelay = 2.2f;
    private float SpawnInterval = 0.1f;
    public bool PlayerAlive;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    private int score;
    public TextMeshProUGUI gameOverText;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore(0);

        InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomEnemy", StartDelay, SpawnInterval);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlayerAlive = true;
    }

    public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {
        score += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }


    void SpawnRandomEnemy()
    {
        int enemyIndex = Random.Range(0, EnemyPrefabs.Length);
        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnRangeX, spawnRangeX), 0, spawnPosZ);
        Instantiate(EnemyPrefabs[enemyIndex], spawnPos, EnemyPrefabs[enemyIndex].transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

In the "player" script, I have a "**private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)**" to have the player be destroyed and activate the "game over" text. I also put a "PlayerAlive = false" there because I'm still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part of your code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    PlayerAlive = true;
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because as long as a `GameManager` instance exists, every frame, the value of `PlayerAlive` will be updated to true, regardless of if you set it to false somewhere else.

You should move that line of code inside your `Start` function to initialize `PlayerAlive` to true.

Now since a specific trigger collider in the `Player` class will set it to false, what you need to do is add a simple check to `UpdateScore` like so:

```
public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd)
{
    // if player is dead, then do nothing
    if(!PlayerAlive) return;

    score += scoreToAdd;
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: I'll try this out when I get time. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still having trouble stopping the score (or the spheres) from going on player death. I don't know what this did for me actually.

Comment: If you added the if statement that checks if the player is dead or not in `UpdateScore`, then there is no way that the score is getting updated from that function, unless you somehow still have the `PlayerAlive` boolean equal to true after death, or you're adding score from somewhere else. I suggest you look where you're assigning the value of `PlayerAlive` and what functions are you using to add score.